# Emptiness of certain linear systems on some hypersurfaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth hypersurface of degree $d \geq 5$ in $\mathbb P^3$ over complex numbers. Let $C$ be a smooth hyperplane section of $X$. Let $D$ be a non-zero effective divisor on $X$ such that the values of $h^0(\mathcal O_X(D))$, $C.D$ and $D^2$ are known. Does there exist a general technique in the literature to investigate emptiness or non-emptiness of the linear system $|(d-4)C-D|$?

For example, let $d=6, D^2= -10, C.D =5, h^0(\mathcal O_X(D))=1$, then is it necessarily true that the linear system $|2C-D|$ is empty?(Note that in this situation emptiness of the linear system $|2C-D|$ is same as vanishing of first cohomology of $\mathcal O_X(D)$)

I have attempted to construct concrete counterexample by starting with $X :x^6+y^6+z^6+w^6 =0$ and $C : y^6+z^6+w^6 =0$ but I am unable to find appropriate $D$ satisfying those conditions.

Also  if in some other cases the linear system turns out to be non-empty, then  can we explicitly find out its dimension?

Any insight from anyone is welcome

Comment: Start from a conic $A$ and a plane cubic $B$ in $\mathbb{P}^3$ (in different planes) which meet transversally at one point. It should be a standard exercise to prove that there is a smooth sextic surface $X$ containing $A$ and $B$. Then $D:=A+B$ does the job.

Comment: @abx, if we instead look at the situation $d=6, D^2=0, C.D=10, h^0(\mathcal O_X(D))=1$, then what should be the intuition? Should we again look for a counterexample or a proof of the fact that $|2C-D|$ is empty?

Comment: I think it is empty. If not, it contains a curve of degree 2; since $(2C-D)^2=-16$ it must be twice a line. But then $D$ would have $h^0>1$.